# Looking for a Shiltei ha-Gibborim citation

Tags: sources-mekorot, rishonim

The Oxford Handbook of Judaism and Economics (page 435, footnote 50, available on Google Books preview [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4EYeDZpAF7UC&pg=PA435&lpg=PA435&dq=tanchuma%20judah%20joseph%20alive%20excommunication&source=bl&ots=AYrrcJMZRh&sig=ACfU3U2_Xp3grYIrjWCK4icdktbs8X1-Bw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiumq_NzZvmAhUVShUIHTh2AUEQ6AEwDnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=tanchuma%20judah%20joseph%20alive%20excommunication&f=false)) refers to a comment in the Shiltei ha-Gibborim. The only precise reference is "note 3 on Mordekhai 475". I have no clue how to find this or look it up. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you edit in some basic expected content that one would find there? Thats the only way to know if a searcher got it right

Comment: I can't see the footnote in the book. Google won't let me. This is why you should include info in the question instead of behind links which can break.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the standard edition of Mordechai (in the back of many volumes of Shas) there are paragraph marks in bold, which are continuous throughout each seder, as in this example:

[image]

So paragraph 475 (תעה) is in Bava Basra, and the Shiltei Hagiborim being referenced is at the foot of the page (the next page, in this case). [Here's](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=37965#p=710&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=) the link.

Comment: This is really helpful (link and explanation!) thanks